# Is there a way to use I.Click to click a declared number?

Tags: jquery, fluentautomation

Is there a way to use I.Click to click a declared number?
It can't use `I.Click("#searchBox", x, y);` to click the button.
It just can use like this `I.Click("#ui table tbody tr(week) td(dayofweek) a");`
The 'week' and 'dayofweek' is declared by myself.
But it's a fixed name inside I.Click and that make it can't work.
Or how can I alter it and that it work?

I want to click the day inside datepicker.
And I only find this way to click it.

Comment: It's totally unclear what you are asking about...

Comment: If you're talking about finding out which date was chosen using jQuery's datepicker widget, put some logic into the [`onSelect()` callback](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) to determine what to do with the date that has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

something like (I assumed you want to click the link in tr that contains a  tag that contains week number and that contains week number and is inside the td)

```
int week=1;
int dayofweek=4;
I.Click("#ui table tbody tr:has(a:contains("+week+")) td a:contains("+week+") ")
```

but the limitation is that "contains" fetches tag contains the string,so "a:contains(1)" can't distinguish 1 or 12.